# I want Distinct value from a column and orderby another column from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want Distinct value from a column and orderby another column from a mysql database.
mysql table has following data

```
_________________________
|id |publisher_id |view |
|1  |1            |6    |
|2  |4            |4    |
|3  |1            |3    |
|4  |3            |2    |
|5  |4            |3    |
|6  |2            |1    |
|7  |3            |7    |
|8  |5            |9    |
-------------------------
```

I want output as follow

```
_________________________
|id |publisher_id |view |
|8  |5            |9    |
|7  |2            |7    |
|1  |1            |6    |
|2  |4            |4    |
-------------------------
```

**Laravel Query**

```
Feed::query()->select('publisher_id', 'view')->distinct()->orderBy('view', 'DESC')->limit(4)->get();
```

Comment: Your query looks fine what is the issue ?

Comment: If you don’t need the id you could `select publisher_id,max(view) from table group by publisher_id`. And might need to,join that to get a(!) valid Id for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of [eckes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13189/eckes)

```
$feeds = \App\Models\Feed::select('publisher_id', \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw('MAX(view) as view'))
        ->orderBy('view', 'DESC')
        ->groupBy('publisher_id')
        ->get();
```

You cannot use `DISTINCT` here, because `DISTINCT` is applied on whole row.

Answer (score -1):

You can distinct on any column,like

```
Feed::query()->select('publisher_id', 'view')->distinct('publisher_id')->orderBy('view', 'DESC')->limit(4)->get();
```

Distinct and order both are different and it does not effect on each other.

Or you can use group by instead of Distinct, like

```
 Feed::query()->select('publisher_id', 'view')->groupBy('publisher_id')->orderBy('view', 'DESC')->limit(4)->get();
```

Comment: *You can distinct on any column* Nope in mysql distinct will applied on whole row not on column